# Update a scope variable from a module in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've the following module:

```
var mod;

mod = angular.module('ajax-interceptor', []);

mod.config(function($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(["$q", function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                //want to update a scope variable when a request is placed
                return config;
            },

            'requestError': function(rejection) {
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },

            'response': function(response) {
                return response;
            },

            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);
});
```

I want to to update a scope variable whenever a request is placed. How can I do that? I can't inject `$scope` in the config block. I'll use this variable to keep track the activity of the user, like a user not requesting for 10 min the user will be forcefully logged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a factory to your module and keep track of user activities in it:

```
mod.factory("factoryName", [
    function(){
        var factory = {};
        factory.track = function(userActivity){
            // Save user activity
        };

        return factory;
    }
]);
```

Then you must inject the factory into $httpProvider and use it:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(["$q", "factoryName", function($q, factoryName, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            //want to update a scope variable when a request is placed
            factoryName.track(userActivity);
            return config;
        }
    };
}]);
```